# How to display values from multiple textbox(vb net) to mysql database in column form

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a database in MySQL named database1 and a table named records. I am trying to add the contents on my textboxes(3 textboxes) to my MySQL database in column form, not in row form. 
Is it possible with `concat`???

The output I want
[image]

Here is my code, I created a row for typeofservice2, and typeofservice3but I only want one, which is type of service, and it looks like this 
What I did[image]

```
Query = "insert into database1.records (dateoftrans,typeofservice,typeofservice2,typeofservice3) values('" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & tos & "','" & tos2 & "','" & tos3 & "')"
```

tos, tos2, and tos3 are my textboxes

Hope someone can help me

Comment: So you want 4 rows with the 4 values, but a row of your table has five columns. In which column do you want to store the 4 textboxes content?

Comment: @Steve I just edited my question, sorry my mistake. I want my type of transactions in column and not in row so it wont look messy. and I only want one column which is "typeofservice"

Comment: @MarikitAvendano Based on your expected output after the insert how will you identify a row in column `typeofservice`. For example, let's consider `Flyers` there is no another column to identify it or did you missed `ID` column ?

Comment: @wingedpanther I have a primary key "transno" and I don't know if the thing that I want is possible to achieve or not because of the primary key

Comment: @MarikitAvendano Could you provide the complete structure(DDL) of the table in which you want to insert the data ?

Comment: it looks like that you want to create a column before inserting the data? Am I correct?

Comment: You have to loop over the four textboxes and call an insert for each (if it is not empty). This will give different "transno" to each inserted record. If this is not acceptable then you need another related table. In the first table you insert the a single record with the date and get back a transno, in the second table you add a record for each textbox with the accompanying transno as foreign key to the first table

Comment: You mean that you want to make a column called typeofservice,typeofservice2 and 3 and insert the data below them like Brochuew,Letterhead,Vin Diesel and so on?

Comment: no @ShadowFiend I dont want a typeofservicce2 and 3 columns, I only want one, the "typeofservice"

Comment: @Steve I will try your suggestion, thank you

Comment: @MarikitAvendano i hope this one is right do you mean you have 3 textboxes `(for typeofservice,typeofservice2,typeofservice3)` and the goal you want is to save it in one column only and that is `typeofservice`?

Comment: @ShadowFiend Yes my friend. Is that possible?

Comment: @MarikitAvendano absolutely yes but do you care if the data is the same? i mean save the data if it is already exist.

Comment: @ShadowFiend No I do not, I just want to achieve that output

Comment: @MarikitAvendano pls wait for my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @ShadowFiend

Comment: @MarikitAvendano what did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first the question for me is quite tricky but then I get your point, I give it a shot.

your current query is this.

`Query = "insert into database1.records (dateoftrans,typeofservice,typeofservice2,typeofservice3) values('" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & tos & "','" & tos2 & "','" & tos3 & "')"`

The best way i can give to you is this..
Create 3 x Insert Command and each Query has there own tos(textbox name). do something like this.

`Query1 = insert into database1.records(dateoftrans,typeofservice) values('" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & tos & "')`

`Query2 = insert into database1.records(dateoftrans,typeofservice) values('" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & tos2 & "')`

`Query2 = insert into database1.records(dateoftrans,typeofservice) values('" & TextBox12.Text & "','" & tos3 & "')`

by that you can save all the values in same column.

Comment: Thank you! By looking at it, I can see that It can work, I am trying it now.